# PHP Regular Expression will not match accented characters

Tags: php, regex, validation, utf-8, expression

I am trying to build a regular expression, compatible with PHP that will allow accented characters, for example 'ü'.
From what I understand the \p{L} operator should do this. What I have so far:

```
/^[a-z0-9\p{L}][a-z0-9_\p{L}]*/i
```

This should allow a string that can start with any a-z, 0-9 and accented characters and can then be followed by any amount of a-z, 0-9 and accented characters and the entire expression is case insensitive.

However in testing, when using characters such as 'ü' anywhere in the string, the validation fails.
I have made sure the value being passed is encoded with utf8 by using:

```
utf8_encode($value)
```

However it still fails. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

-------------------------Edit-------------------------

After testing on another server, the original pattern also works.

```
/^[a-z0-9\p{L}][a-z0-9_\p{L}]*/i
```

The issue appears to be with the server set up.
I will post the solution when found.

Comment: Try turning on the utf modifier `/.../ui`

Comment: Unfortunately no success with the utf modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might work for you:

```
$pattern =  '/^[0-9a-zá-úàü][0-9_a-zá-úàü]*$/i';
```

I ran the following code to test the pattern:

```
$str = "patinação";
$pattern =  '/^[0-9a-zá-úàü][0-9_a-zá-úàü]*$/i';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)){
    echo $matches[0];//output: patinação
}
```

Comment: Same result as before, it will not register with any accented characters.

Comment: @dooffas -  I just tested it, and edited my answer to show the test and result. If it's not working for you, I don't know why, because it's working fine here.

Comment: i agree, even the first code given by user himself works fine on my machine. looks like pcre unicode is not enabled on your web server.

Comment: Interestingly this works on another web server. Although an edit needs to be made to your response. $str and $pattern are round the wrong way.
The problem I am having must be due to the server set up. Thanks for your help.